# WPF MVVM Navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Following a lot of research and mainly based on [this tutorial](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/) I came up with the following structure in my application:
**ObjectBase - all view models inherit it:**

```
public abstract class ObjectBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    protected void SetProperty<T>(ref T member, T val,
       [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (object.Equals(member, val)) return;

        member = val;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged

    public abstract ObjectBase BackLocation { get; }

    public abstract event Action<ObjectBase> NavigateTo;

    public abstract string ViewHeader { get; }
}
```

**Main Content ViewModel:**

```
public class MainContentViewModel : ObjectBase
{
    private ObjectBase _selectedView;
    public ObjectBase SelectedView
    {
        get { return _selectedView; }
        set
        {
            if (SelectedView != null)
            {
                SelectedView.NavigateTo -= SelectedView_NavigateTo;
            }
            if (SelectedView is IDisposable)
            {
                (SelectedView as IDisposable).Dispose();
            }

            SetProperty(ref _selectedView, value);
            SelectedView.NavigateTo += SelectedView_NavigateTo;
        }
    }

    public MainContentViewModel()
    {
        SelectedView = new ViewModels.FirstViewModel();
    }

    private void SelectedView_NavigateTo(ObjectBase viewToNavigateTo)
    {
        SelectedView = viewToNavigateTo;
    }

    #region Back Command
    private CommandBase _backCommand;

    public CommandBase BackCommand
    {
        get { return _backCommand ?? (_backCommand = new CommandBase(Back)); }
    }

    private void Back(object obj)
    {
        if (SelectedView.BackLocation != null)
        {
            SelectedView = SelectedView.BackLocation;
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
        }
    }
    #endregion Back Command

    #region ObjectBase Fields
    public override event Action<ObjectBase> NavigateTo;
    public override string ViewHeader { get { return "Main View"; } }
    public override ObjectBase BackLocation { get { return null; } }
    #endregion
}
```

**Main Content View:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfNavigationTest.Views.MainContentView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:WpfNavigationTest.Views"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:WpfNavigationTest.ViewModels">
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:MainContentViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:FirstViewModel}">
        <views:FirstView/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:SecondViewModel}">
        <views:SecondView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Go Back" Command="{Binding BackCommand}"/>
    <Separator Margin="0,15" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectedView}" Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
```

**Sample View Model 1:**

```
public class FirstViewModel : ObjectBase
{
    #region GoForward Command
    private CommandBase _goForwardCommand;
    public CommandBase GoForwardCommand
    {
        get { return _goForwardCommand ?? (_goForwardCommand = new CommandBase(GoForward)); }
    }
    private void GoForward(object obj)
    {
        NavigateTo(new ViewModels.SecondViewModel(DateTime.Now.ToString()));
    }
    #endregion
    public override ObjectBase BackLocation { get { return null; } }
    public override string ViewHeader { get { return "First View"; } }

    public override event Action<ObjectBase> NavigateTo;
}
```

**Sample View Model 2:**

```
public class SecondViewModel : ObjectBase
{
    private string _addMessage;

    public SecondViewModel(string addedMessage)
    {
        _addMessage = addedMessage;
    }

    public override ObjectBase BackLocation { get { return new ViewModels.FirstViewModel(); } }

    public override string ViewHeader { get { return $"Second View. Message: {_addMessage}"; } }

    public override event Action<ObjectBase> NavigateTo;
}
```

In general, this works as expected but I would like to know if I'm at the right direction and how can I improve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. I think `ObjectBase` name is too generic. Class name should reflect its purpose. `ViewModelBase` is an example of better naming. Same goes for `FirstViewModel` and `SecondViewModel`.
2. Using `as` operator after using `is` should generally be avoided. You should either use `is` and then use strong cast, or use `as` and then a `null` check. The second option is usually better since this way you only cast object once.
3. You should split your `ObjectBase` class in two. One class to contain `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation, which you will use in your view models (`ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged`), and another class to contain page-specific properties, such as header, "back" reference, etc. (`PageViewModelBase : ViewModelBase`).
4. `SelectedView` is really confusing name for a property, which holds a view model reference.
5. There is a potential issue with your `SelectedView` setter. Calling `SelectedView = SelectedView` will probably crash your software, as it will leave `SelectedView` in disposed state. You should check viewmodels for equality first, and only then you should dispose the old viewmodel (your `SetProperty` method does not currently allow that).
6. Your `Back` method has a similar issue, as it might set `SelectedView` to already disposed object.
7. I would also use `Stack` in your `MainContentViewModel` to store back locations instead of storing them in each individual page. Otherwise you will run into issues for more complex scenarious such as "page1 -> page2 -> page3 -> page2". Will you be able to return to page1? Or will you circle between page2 and page3 instead?
8. I think you should avoid using events in this scenario, it complicates things too much. Use interfaces instead.

Might look like this:

```
interface IPageManager
{
    void Back();
    void Forward<T>() where T : IPage;
}

interface IPage
{
    bool CanRestore { get; }
    string Header { get; }
    void Open();
    void Close();
}

class MainContentViewModel : ViewModelBase, IPageManager
{
    private Stack<IPage> _navigationHistory = new Stack<IPage>();

    private IPage _selectedPage;
    public IPage SelectedPage
    {
        get { return _selectedPage; }
        set
        {
            if (Object.Equals(_selectedPage, value)) return;
            if (_selectedPage != null)
            {
                _selectedPage.Close();
            }
            SetProperty(ref _selectedPage, value);
            _selectedPage.Open();
        }
    }

    public void Back()
    {
        while (_navigationHistory.Any())
        {
            var page = _navigationHistory.Pop();
            if (!page.CanRestore) continue;
            SelectedPage = page;
            return;
        }

        Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
    }

    public void Forward<T>() where T : IPage
    {
        _navigationHistory.Push(SelectedPage);
        SelectedPage = YourViewModelFactory.Create<T>();
    }

   ........
}

class LoginViewModel : ViewModelBase, IPage
{
    private readonly IPageManager _manager;

    public LoginViewModel(IPageManager manager)
    {
        _manager = manager;
    }

    public string Header
    {
        get { return "Login"; }
    }

    public bool CanRestore 
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void Open()
    {
    }

    public void Close()
    {
    }

    private CommandBase _goForwardCommand;
    public CommandBase GoForwardCommand
    {
        get { return _goForwardCommand ?? (_goForwardCommand = new CommandBase(GoForward)); }
    }
    private void GoForward(object obj)
    {
        _manager.Forward<WelcomeViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. in regards to section 3, I don't see a `SelectedView = SelectedView` in my setter

Comment: In regards to your recommendation about using a `Stack` I'm not sure how this can solve a situation where the back location may vary according to some logic. setting a new instance of the back location explicitly wouldn't make it safer to use?

Comment: also, the main reason that I implemented this as above is in order to have the ability to pass parameters to the constructor of the forward location

Comment: Its just an exmaple of a scenario, where your setter will dispose object and keep the disposed reference as your `SelectedView`.

Comment: I don't see any problems with navigating to different view depending on some context. You just have to call `Forward<T>` with different `T`, and thats it. If you also need to pass an argument, then you can add an argument. Make it `void Foraward<T>(object args = null)` or something. The point here is to separate viewmodel creation logic from the rest of your code (by implementing some kind of factory), otherwise you will find yourself copypasting huge chunks of code as soon as your navigation becomes more complex.

Comment: good point. is the general approach on using UserControls inside a ContentPresenter is a good one?

Comment: Sure, why not. Your `xaml` looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: How would you implement a scenario where back isn't necessary the last view?

Comment: I would probably add a new property to `IPage` interface, which will allow me to skip pages I don't want restored. I've updated my answer.

Comment: what are the `Close()` and `Open()` used for?

Comment: To initialize model before opening the page (for example, fetch some data from DB), and to clean up resources before navigating away (for example, to close DB connection). Remove those methods if you feel like you do not need them.

Comment: One last question :) what would be the best approach for passing the `IPageManager` instance to the view models? I guess that this would be a good place for `Dependency Injection` however, the context of the `IPageManager` will always be the same one over the life time of the application and AFAIK DI is supposed to create a new instance when used.

Comment: All `DI` frameworks I know allow you to set up lifestyle of every object you register. It can be singleton (meaning there will be single instance of given object inside the container) or transient (the behaviour you describe). Or it can follow some custom policy you implement. `DI` is pretty flexible, so yeh, you should use it.